# Control an embedded video through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about seeking or pausing an embedded video (not necessarily a swf) from javascript? I am looking for something like Google's SWFObject's API, but for Windows Media Player, Real Player, Quicktime.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could use the HTML5 element "Video" =/  There are a few examples of that all over

Comment: However, the video tag doesn't support a "ton" of video formats.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [camen design](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody), that is for backup (in case HTML 5 is not available), then [broken links](http://www.broken-links.com/tests/video.html) (set the src attribute of the video tag to something else, ironic enough that link to the video *is* broken), you can easily play/ pause, access volume control, etc using Javascript.

Like ItzWarty said, not many video formats are supported, but you can certainly work it out.

Comment: I'm the owner of the site Broken Links which is referenced by Tom; if you want to see the video demo working, take a look in a WebKit browser; the .ogg file I referenced has been removed, so the demo will only work in WebKit until I can create a new one.